# Writing a stream of content to file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file, pdf, stream

I have a variable which holds a stream of content .
The variable is speicified as shown below ,

```
Task<Stream> tempStream = ....
```

Specifically this tempStream variable holds a A pdf stream.

I want to to write this stream into a file .  How can I do this in c# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work:

```
 path = @"Path\\to\\output";    
 using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
 {
     tempStream.CopyTo(outpoutFileStream);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I get the error Task<Stream> does not contain a definition for CopyTo . Any idea on how to resolve that ?

Comment: This tempStream you are referring to is a Task that returns a stream.
You should await that task and declare tempStream as a Stream type instead.

Comment: I tried it with adding Result.CopyTo and it worked too . Is awaiting a better approach here ?

Comment: It is probably the best approach, please read further about Async/Await [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).